# SQLCipher with Windows Phone 8 unable to encrypt a plain text database on device and then query it

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, sqlcipher

Is anyone currently doing this on Windows Phone 8 with SqlCipher? I'm communicating with them on their GitHub board, but I'm down to the wire without a solution at this point - here's an example:

```
public void Encrypt(string newpassword) {
    string encryptedDb = _dbConnection + "_";

    File.Delete(encryptedDb);

    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbConnection, _dbPassword)) {
        //attachResult == 0
        int attachResult = db.Execute(string.Format("ATTACH DATABASE '{0}' AS encrypted KEY '{1}'", encryptedDb, newpassword));
        //exportResult == null
        string exportResult = db.ExecuteScalar<String>("select sqlcipher_export('encrypted')");
        //detachResult == 0
        int detachResult = db.Execute("DETACH DATABASE encrypted");
        db.Close();
    }

    //confirmed in storage 2 files db.s3db (unencrypted 25.0K) and db.s3db_(encrupted 27.0K)
    File.Copy(encryptedDb, _dbConnection, true);
    File.Delete(encryptedDb);

    //one remaining file db.s3db (encrypted with 'newpassword')

    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbConnection, newpassword)) {
        //throws "file is not a database or is encrypted"
        int records = db.ExecuteScalar<int>("select count(*) from sqlite_master;");
        db.Close();
    }
}
```

No file produced by this, maybe that's expected and no exceptions thrown:

```
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbConnection, "")) {

            int attachResult = db.Execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'plaintext.db' AS plaintext KEY ''");

            string exportResult = db.ExecuteScalar<String>("SELECT sqlcipher_export('plaintext')");

            int detachResult = db.Execute("DETACH DATABASE plaintext");
            db.Close();
        }
```

This also fails at the indicated point:

```
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbConnection, "")) {
            //attachResult == 0
            int attachResult = db.Execute(string.Format("ATTACH DATABASE '{0}' AS encrypted KEY '{1}'", encryptedDb, "12345"));
            //exportResult == null
            string exportResult = db.ExecuteScalar<String>("select sqlcipher_export('encrypted')");
            //detachResult == 0
            int detachResult = db.Execute("DETACH DATABASE encrypted");
            db.Close();
        }

        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(encryptedDb, "12345")) {
            //fails - 'Non db'
            int attachResult = db.Execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'plaintext.db' AS plaintext KEY ''");

            string exportResult = db.ExecuteScalar<String>("SELECT sqlcipher_export('plaintext')");

            int detachResult = db.Execute("DETACH DATABASE plaintext");
            db.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved, it was related to a local user setup, not an issue with SQLCipher.  Details of the resolution can be found [here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/issues/84#issuecomment-38005801).